I need an Attorney in civil litigation for premises liability which complaint has been entered by pro se litigant
slipped on substance in floor of walmart 2022.  Had an attorney who dropped case 3 months from deadline. I have photos of floor, not very clear video from incident.  An employee looking in the direction in video, all my medical records, due to incident was responsible for 2 fusion surgeries which I have had.  I am not an Attorney but had to make deadline of 2 years.  We have just began discovery and are on a 8 month deadline with a jury trial in ga.  I need a litigation Attorney that will stand by me.

Certainly not here. This site is not for finding attorneys or lawyers for work.
